# How do I give every single image a unique link that opens in a new resizable window?

Tags: javascript, tabs, onclick, window

```
<img onClick="openWindow()" src="Image1.jpg"/>
<script>
function openWindow() {
window.open("http://www.Google.com","mywin","menubar=1,resizable=1,width=500,height=500");
}
</script>

<img onClick="openWindow()" src="Image2.jpg"/>
<script>
function openWindow() {
window.open("http://www.YouTube.com","mywin","menubar=1,resizable=1,width=500,height=500");
}
</script>
```

I'm using the code above to open a link/url in a new resizable window, when people click on an image. I want to use more then just one image. But when I change the link for the second/next image, the function always run that link. So also for the first iamge. **How do I give every single image a unique link that opens in a new resizable window with the code above?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function openWindow(url, wname) {         
  window.open(url,wname,"menubar=1,resizable=1,width=500,height=500");
}
</script>

<img onClick="openWindow('http://www.Google.com', 'mywin1')" src="Image1.jpg"/>
<img onClick="openWindow('http://www.YouTube.com', 'mywin2')" src="Image2.jpg"/>
```